# Tkinter Multiprocessing Namerror: name 'logarea' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

I am using the following code, but i am getting "NameError: name 'logarea' is not defined"

```
from tkinter import *
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Queue
import os
from tkinter import ttk
import logging
import datetime



curr_dir = os.getcwd()

def browserRun():
    global curr_dir
    timenow = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    logname = rf'{curr_dir}\Logs\Log-{timenow}.txt'
    logging.basicConfig(filename=logname,
                        filemode='a',
                        format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
                        level=logging.INFO,
                        force=True)
    while True:
        global driver
        options = Options()
        options.binary_location = r'D:\Downloads\Chromedriver\browser\chrome.exe'
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:\Downloads\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
        driver.get('http://google.com')
        logging.info(f"Logging to gmail")
        loggingtoUI(logname)
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@name="q"]').send_keys("Hello World")
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()

def start():
    global executor
    pqueue = Queue()
    executor = [multiprocessing.Process(target=browserRun) for _ in range(1)]
    for p in executor:
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()


def loggingtoUI(logname):
    global myfile
    global logarea
    with open(logname, "r") as myfile:
        try:
            MyText2 = myfile.read()
            logarea.config(state='normal')
            logarea.delete('1.0', END)
            logarea.insert(INSERT, MyText2)
            logarea.see("end")
            logarea.config(state='disabled')
        finally:
            myfile.close()




def stop():
    global executor
    for p in executor:
        p.terminate()
    # os.system("taskkill /F /IM chromedriver.exe /T")
    os.system("taskkill /F /IM CHROME.exe /T")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    global logarea
    root = Tk()
    notebook = ttk.Notebook(root, style='lefttab.TNotebook')
    tab1 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
    tab2 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
    notebook.add(tab1, text="Home")
    notebook.add(tab2, text="Settings")
    notebook.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    button = Button(tab1, text="start", command=start)
    button.place(x=20, y=20)
    button1 = Button(tab1, text="stop", command=stop)
    button1.place(x=70, y=20)
    logarea = Text(tab1, height=25, width=40, wrap='word', state='disabled')
    logarea.place(x=120, y=40)
    root.geometry("500x500")
    root.mainloop()
```

I set the logarea to global, but still i am getting NameError, i tried set the logarea as global in start and inload of the code, but nothing works.

The issue happens when i call loggingtoUI in another function. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: first of you don't need to use `global logarea`, second, you don't need to use `try/finally` in the `with` context manager because that is exactly what it does implicitly. and `logarea` is defined

Comment: Matiiss, Thanks for the help, but it doesnt worked, i take off `try/finally global logarea` but still it shows `NameError: name 'logarea' is not defined`, it happens at `logarea.config(state='normal')`

Comment: Data is not shared across processes.

Comment: acw1668, Thanks for the help, When i add `print` after `MyText2 = myfile.read()` iam able to see the read data

Comment: It is from a file, not data in the process.

Comment: `logarea` is not shared between processes, and you can't even share it because it is not pickleable (none of `tkinter` stuff is), what you need is probably to use `multiprocessing.Queue` or `multiprocessing.Manager` to share data with the main process and use an `.after` "loop" to update the text widget

Comment: Matiiss, Thanks for the advise, it would be grateful if you share a example of it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer, thanks for the help guys

```
from queue import Empty, Full
import tkinter as Tk
import multiprocessing
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import logging
import datetime
import time
import os
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
import random
import tempfile



logname = ''
curr_dir = os.getcwd()

class GuiApp(object):
   def __init__(self, q):
      self.root = Tk()
      self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.root, style='lefttab.TNotebook')
      self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
      self.tab2 = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
      self.notebook.add(self.tab1, text="Home")
      self.notebook.add(self.tab2, text="Settings")
      self.notebook.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
      self.button = Button(self.tab1, text="start", command=self.start)
      self.button.place(x=20, y=20)
      self.button1 = Button(self.tab1, text="stop", command=self.stop)
      self.button1.place(x=70, y=20)
      self.logarea = Text(self.tab1, height=25, width=40, wrap='word', state='disabled')
      self.logarea.place(x=120, y=40)
      self.root.geometry("500x500")
      self.root.after(100, self.CheckQueuePoll, q)

   def CheckQueuePoll(self, c_queue):
      global logname
      try:
         MyText2 = c_queue.get(0)
         self.logarea.config(state='normal')
         self.logarea.delete('1.0', END)
         self.logarea.insert('end', MyText2)
         self.logarea.config(state='disabled')
      except Empty:
         pass
      finally:
         self.root.after(100, self.CheckQueuePoll, c_queue)

   def start(self):
      global executor
      executor = [multiprocessing.Process(target=GenerateData,args=(q,)) for _ in range(2)]
      for p in executor:
         p.start()
      # t1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=GenerateData,args=(q,))
      # t1.start()

   def stop(self):
      # t1.terminate()
      for p in executor:
         p.terminate()
      os.system("taskkill /F /IM chromedriver.exe /T")
      # os.system("taskkill /F /IM CHROME.exe /T")


def GenerateData(q):
   global logname
   global curr_dir
   timenow = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
   logname = rf'{curr_dir}\Logs\Log-{timenow}.txt'
   logging.basicConfig(filename=logname,
                          filemode='a',
                          format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s',
                          datefmt='%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
                          level=logging.INFO,
                          force=True)
   while True:
      options = uc.ChromeOptions()
      rand_num = random.randint(0000, 9999)
      temp = tempfile.gettempdir()
      temp_dir = rf'{temp}/temp{rand_num}'
      options.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir={temp_dir}')
      options.add_argument('--no-first-run --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic --disable-notifications')
      options.binary_location = rf'{curr_dir}\drivers\Browser\chrome.exe'
      driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path=rf'{curr_dir}\drivers\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
      driver.get('http://google.com')
      logging.info(f"Logging to gmail")
      f = open(logname, "r")
      q.put(f.read())
      time.sleep(5)
      driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@name="q"]').send_keys("Hello World")
      time.sleep(5)
      driver.close()
      driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   q = multiprocessing.Queue()
   q.cancel_join_thread()  # or else thread that puts data will not term
   gui = GuiApp(q)
   gui.root.mainloop()
```